# Why does auto borrowing not occur in Rust if I implement `TryFrom` for a reference type?

Tags: rust

Let's say I want to implement a conversion on a reference. In this case, it's a conversion from `&f64 -> Foo`.

```rust
use std::convert::{TryFrom, TryInto};

struct Foo {
    a: f64
}

impl TryFrom<&f64> for Foo {
    type Error = String;

    fn try_from(value: &f64) -> Result<Foo, String> {
        Ok(Foo {
            a: *value
        })
    }
}

fn main(){
    let foo: Foo = 5.0.try_into().unwrap();
    let bar: Foo = (&5.0).try_into().unwrap();
}
```

(Yes of course this is a pointless and stupid example, but it helps simplify the problem)

Now, the second line in the main method, with manual borrowing, succeeds.
However, the first line in the main method, without the manual borrowing, fails with this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo: From<{float}>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:18:24
   |
18 |     let foo: Foo = 5.0.try_into().unwrap();
   |                        ^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<{float}>` is not implemented for `Foo`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<Foo>` for `{float}`
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryFrom<{float}>` for `Foo`
  --> src/main.rs:7:6
   |
7  | impl TryFrom<&f64> for Foo {
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryInto<Foo>` for `{float}`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c877310192e3ccabc97eb459b552cd09)

Why is automatic borrowing not working here?

Comment: cause... it's not implemented ? I don't know what to say. you expect rust auto reference ? rust do that on some specific place but not here that all, note you can implement both `TryFrom<&f64>` and `TryFrom<f64>`

Comment: rust only auto borrow for self, TryFrom doesn't take self as parameter

Comment: @Stargateur: there's a blanket [`impl<T, U> TryInto<U> for T where U: TryFrom<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html#impl-TryInto%3CU%3E), and `try_into` takes `self` (I suspect the problem here is that it doesn't take `&self`).

Comment: why this blanked implementation would work since `impl TryFrom<f64> for Foo` is not implemented ?

Comment: what you may seek is this kind of blanked implementation https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-13 but this is not a thing in tryfrom

Comment: Yes, I'm implicitly relying on the `impl` that @eggyal refers to.

Comment: @Stargateur Note it's "blanket" implementation, like what you cover a bed with (because it covers many types like a blanket). "Blanked" is a different word and would mean made blank or cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error message suggests, the problem is `the trait bound Foo: From<{float}> is not satisfied`. When matching traits, Rust will not perform any coercion but **probing the suitable method**. This is actually documented in [*The Rustonomicon*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html), reads

> Note that we do not perform coercions when matching traits (except for receivers, see the next page). If there is an impl for some type U and T coerces to U, that does not constitute an implementation for T.

and the [next page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dot-operator.html) says

> Suppose we have a function foo that has a receiver (a self, &self or &mut self parameter). If we call value.foo(), the compiler needs to determine what type Self is before it can call the correct implementation of the function. ... If it can't call this function (for example, if the function has the wrong type or a trait isn't implemented for Self), then the compiler tries to add in an automatic reference. This means that the compiler tries <&T>::foo(value) and <&mut T>::foo(value). This is called an "autoref" method call.

So when matching the trait bound, Rust compiler will try to auto ref/deref on the type only. In addition, the dot operator in rust is just a syntax sugar of fully qualified function call. Thus `5.0.try_into().unwrap();` will become `f64::try_into(5.0).unwrap();` and since `TryInto` is not implemented for `f64`, Rust will try to auto reference it by calling `&f64::try_into(5.0).unwrap();`. Now the compiler can find a version of `TryInto` implemented for `&f64`, however the type of argument still doesn't match: `try_into` for `&f64` requires `&f64` as parameter type, while the current call provides `f64`, and Rust compiler cannot do any coercion on parameters when checking trait bound. Thus the trait bound still doesn't match (`&f64` cannot take `f64` argument) and the check failed. Thus you will see the error message.

Comment: Interesting, so if the receiver can be coerced before matching traits, I could implement `TryInto<Foo>` for `&f64` and it would work?

Comment: Apparently not: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5937f5fc106d80d3bad9562e0f7282c.

Comment: @Migwell The problem is that the parameter type doesn't match. In your code `5.0.try_into().unwrap();` will become `<&f64>::try_into(5.0).unwrap();`, which still has the same problem.  You may also refer to https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0277 to see a detailed explanation of "E0277" error code.